# How do I catch OCUnit's test fail/success in command line?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, jenkins, ocunit

My Expect: # Build Successed # and # Test Failed #

Actual Result: only # Build Succeeded #

How do I get fail/success in command line? [iphone, objective-c, xcode4, OCUnit]

I'm newbe of OCUnit and Xcode4. I create project:
https://github.com/sanemat/HogeHoge
This is scafold code by xcode4. I run test in xcode gui, #Test Failed# appear in successfully. In commandline (I want to use jenkins),I use following command.

```
xcodebuild -target HogeHogeTests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.3 clean build
```

I see # Build Succeeded # and then completed. I want run test and get it's result. How?

Edited:

I found [BPOCUnitXMLReporter](https://github.com/threeve/BPOCUnitXMLReporter). This is for MacOS. I [forked](https://github.com/sanemat/BPOCUnitXMLReporter) and adjusted iOS.

Comment: Hi Sanemat, just to put this to bed: The way SO works is you upvote the answers that helped and accept the answer that did it for you. Consider making your edit an answer and after 24h you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [BPOCUnitXMLReporter](https://github.com/threeve/BPOCUnitXMLReporter). This is for MacOS. I [forked](https://github.com/sanemat/BPOCUnitXMLReporter) and adjusted iOS.

Comment: In your forked project, how do you get Jenkins to pull in the ocunit.xml file? Or put another way, how do you pass the simulator's Application's folder into Jenkins?

Comment: I'm satisfied to output xml format, so you can write logs/junit.xml e.g. junit log pattern. Or I recommend to use GHUnit instead of OCUnit. This is more friendly to Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Text Finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) It allows you to search a log for a string, and set pass or fail based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate a custom test logger with OCUnit. See my answer here:
[How do I trap OCUnit test pass/failure messages/events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247607/how-do-i-trap-ocunit-test-pass-failure-messages-events/6149887#6149887)

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is this undocumented argument (you do need sdk and target too) to run your OCUnit Tests from the terminal

```
xcodebuild  -target MyTarget -sdk iphonesimulator   TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES
```